# Positioning an element relative to the object in the photo

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a background photo with small rocket in the center.
`background: center / cover url(image) no-repeat;`
Also I have an image of line which connects rocket and button at the left part of the screen.
When i change the screen size all elements change their position.
I used vh, but it didn't work.
[image]

Comment: what do you want it to do on mobile view exactly?

Comment: Please post minimal code to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use media to get device size and set certain CSS to the object.

```
(example)

/* if mobile device max width 380px */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 380px) {
    .image{
  position:relative;
  top:10px;
  }
}
```